# Converting a list to a data frame making each nested element a column in the df using r

Tags: r, list, dataframe

using r:

I have a list of 100 like this:

```
[[1]]

      A   B
ST1   2   3
ST2   4  10
ST3   5   6

[[2]]

       A   B
ST1    4   8
ST2    5   2
ST3   20  10
```

until 100... They are all in same structure. I know how to combine them into a df where they all fall into three columns vertically. However, what I want is something like this:

```
      A1   B1   A2  B2... A100  B100
ST1   2   3      4   8
ST2   4  10      5   2
ST3   5   6     20  10
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `do.call(cbind, your list)`?

Comment: What does each element look like?  Are they `data.frame`s?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `do.call(cbind` to convert the `list` of `data.frames` into a single `data.frame`

```
df1 <- do.call(cbind, lst)
colnames(df1) <- make.unique(colnames(df1))
```

Or

```
colnames(df1) <- paste0(colnames(df1), rep(seq_along(lst), each=length(lst)))
df1
#    A1 B1 A2 B2
#ST1  2  3  4  8
#ST2  4 10  5  2
#ST3  5  6 20 10
```

Or simply

```
df1 <- data.frame(lst)
```

and change the column names.

Comment: I used that cbind one, exactly the same code. However, it gave me the same three columns everytime. I mean they got the same value. like this:

Comment: @WilliamLiu Do you have data.frames as list elements?

Comment: I do not think I have... The list I got is using lapply to loop something.

Comment: @WilliamLiu Can you show the `dput` output of `lst[[1]]` or `str(lst)`